# How can I align these two divs together

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu div and a paragraph div each in a separate line but I want them glued beside each other.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

link {
  display: none;
}

.vertical-men {
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical-men a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.vertical-men a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-men a.activate {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.container-men {
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
  <meta name="description" content="Example description">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <p id="p1" class="head-1">example</p>

    <img id="imag" alt="logo" src="logo-black.png">

    <br>

  </header>
  <main>

    <div class="vertical-men">
      <a href="#" class="activate">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container-men">

    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I just want the innertext (class="container-men") to be animatedly changed by clicking on each (class="vertical-men")

and also I'd be really grateful if you could give me the Javascript codes for that purpose. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, this forum is not a free programming service - it is for when you have attempted your code and got stuck with a specific problem or error.  Please have an attempt and if you have difficulties, come back with your attempt, and explain what you're having trouble with and why it didn't work

Comment: you can share code on jsFiddle so another user can understand your problem

Comment: @Pete Agreed with your comments

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you try. `CSS-Grid`, `Flexbox`, `Float`... However the modern techniques are to use either `flexbox` or `css-grid`.

Using a CSS-Grid:

You use the container main and change it into a grid layout by applying `display: grid;`. Then you add a 2 column layout with `grid-template-columns: min-content auto;`. That way The navbar will consume as much space as declared and the content all remaining space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

link {
  display: none;
}

.vertical-men {
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical-men a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.vertical-men a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-men a.activate {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.container-men {
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 50%;
}

/* added changes */

.vertical-men {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-men {
  width: auto;
}

main {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
  <meta name="description" content="Example description">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <p id="p1" class="head-1">example</p>

    <img id="imag" alt="logo" src="logo-black.png">

    <br>

  </header>
  <main>

    <div class="vertical-men">
      <a href="#" class="activate">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container-men">

    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Using Flexbox:

In this case you use `display: flex;` on the container (`<main>`). Then you can use `flex-direction: row;` to align the 2 elements next to each other. To span the content the remaining width, you can use `flex-grow: 1;` on the content element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

link {
  display: none;
}

.vertical-men {
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical-men a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.vertical-men a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-men a.activate {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.container-men {
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 50%;
}

/* added changes */

.vertical-men {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-men {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

main {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
  <meta name="description" content="Example description">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <p id="p1" class="head-1">example</p>

    <img id="imag" alt="logo" src="logo-black.png">

    <br>

  </header>
  <main>

    <div class="vertical-men">
      <a href="#" class="activate">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container-men">

    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```